# Save problem for Geometry Dash

Tags: geometry-dash

When I beat electrodynamix, I watched my replay and when I watched it, the app crashed. So when I went back on the app, on electrodynamix it said 88% (that was my record before I beat it.) I tried pressing "load" but that did nothing. I also sent 25 emails to RobTop but that did nothing.
EDIT: I beat electrodynamix but how can prevent this glitch from happening in the future?

Answer (score 1):

You have to save your data in order to load it.

If you saved it after beating electrodynamics, it should load when you press load unless your connection is faulty.

If you didn't save your progress, Geo Dash has a glitch in which erases your past few attempts every time the app closes.

If loading it now doesn't recover the data, nothing will unless RobTop notices you.